# Pub-Sub - Get the Identity of Publisher to the Topic

Tags: google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a requirement to get the Identity of the publisher to the PubSub topic.

For example, if a user publishes the message, I need to capture the user ID.

If a Service Account publishes the message, then I need to capture the Service Account.

Comment: This is regarding Pub-Sub in GCP

Comment: i recommend you edit the post and add this as well as add gcp tag

Comment: Do you mean when receiving the message in the subscriber?

Comment: Yes that's correct, need to know the identity of publisher at subscriber end.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way built into Google Cloud Pub/Sub to know the identity of the publisher on the subscribe side. The only way to get the information would be for the publisher to add it as an attribute when publishing messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can not know userID who send data on the topic. Data can send on the topic only with valid credentials.